# Cannot connect my Raspberry Pi model B to my router via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I've recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and today I tried to set it up according to the recommendations. I've plugged the Raspberry to a power supply, put a Micro SD card and then I've plugged in my Ethernet cable in the correct slot. When I made a quick scan of my network via Fing application, my Raspberry did not show up.

Is this a basic networking problem or something might be wrong with my Ethernet cable? Or maybe the application itself could not detect my Raspberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you'll need to put an Operating System on the Pi before it will be scanned by Fing or any other network scanning application.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a Raspberry Pi on it's own does not contain an OS, so if you put an empty sdcard into the slot it will not show much activity. The easiest way to get it up and running would be to download the New Out Of the Box Software (NOOBS) https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-noobs/ and unpack it onto your SDcard. This will give you a multitude of options for installing all kinds of different things onto your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: and yes, would it be better to install NOOBS instead of Rasbian? just a personal opinion

Comment: Noobs will give you an option to install one of more OS's. One of which is Rasbian.